# clear out all variables without closing terminal

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I want to know how to clear all variables which I defined in command prompt **without closing** terminal ?

for example, if I set a variable in command prompt as:

```
$ a=1
```

now I want to delete the variable `$a` (and many other variables defined in similar way) without closing terminal. I could use `unset` but it will be hectic if there are large no. of variables

Comment: `exec "$0"`maybe - but it's hard to tell what you mean by *global*.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: theyre not global - they're defined somewhere. probably in your profile or rcfile. if so then `exec` is what you want. I once [did an answer in detail on this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154840/52934). maybe look - it was all about clearing the shells memory.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I am working with arrays using script. I sometimes add one element to it. because of which I cant run the script with old values(since array is changed). i have to close the terminal and start a new session again. I hope I made clear. if not please let me know :)

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172244/how-can-i-print-only-variables-defined-inside-my-shell-script/172438#172438

Comment: I would, if I understood what Gilles did. But whatever he did, if you can get a list of variables defined by you using it, then probably you can use unset on them.

Comment: @muru didn't understood thats why I asked :(

Comment: @muru - he gets a list saved to a `$var` with `var=$(declare -p +F);` then passes that as an argument to a function which does `echo "${2%%=*}".` That answer has a few problems with sheer size - but it should work if your environment isn't huge.

Comment: @mikeserv your very first comment `exec "$0"` works. can you please explain it in answer how ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - not like that - that was just a naive command - you need a little more to it to do it right.=. I did explain it - in the link I posted above. It's explained pretty well *(I hope)*. I'd rather not do it twice. Will you read it please and let me know if you need any more help or whatever? Particularly you'll want *not* to do the `set` part in the link I left - that's what migrates vars from old shell to new.

Comment: The short explanation is also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222328/bash-reset-reloading-bash-completely-alias-and-function#comment21462412_15225461

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Are you talking about an interactive shell or a script? Variables set in a script executed from an interactive shell don't affect the parent shell. [Tell us what you want to achieve, not which dead end you're pursuing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Gilles my apologies I should not have mentioned "script".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you do (GNU coreutils)

```
exec env --ignore-environment /bin/bash
```

you will use a fresh & new environment

Comment: what about `exec "$0"` ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds `$0` is the zeroth argument to an executed shell. So, if you're running `bash` `$0` is `bash` *(probably - it might be `-bash` in a `-l`ogin shell case depending on version)*. If you're running a script with a `#!/bin/bash` bangline, `$0` is the path to the script. `exec "$0"` is probably more flexible, but `exec bash` is more explicit. If you enter that command at a terminal, `bash` should recognize it's in an interactive environment and do the equivalent of `bash -i` - which will get your `~/.bashrc` file run as well.

Comment: This doesn't help with `export a=123`, that variable is inherited...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `env`, which is provided by GNU coreutils (typically preinstalled on GNU/Linux systems):

`exec env --ignore-environment /bin/bash`

The exec system call is so that your current process is replaced in-place by the new, environment-less version of your shell.

This has the benefit to also clear any *exported* environment variables.

Comment: But this would clear my modified PATH variable, for example `export PATH=$PATH:~/foo`, right?

Comment: You are right. I've modified my answer so that the absolute path of the shell is used instead of $0.

Comment: Thanks to user30747, stolen your answer to correct mine. Can't delete accepted answer