# Declare non environment variables and print them directly afterwards

Tags: bash, variable, testing, trace

I want to declare a few *non environment variables* and print them directly afterwards.

For example:

```
read domain &&
web_application_root="${HOME}/www" &&
domain_dir="${web_application_root}/${domain}/public_html" &&
```

**What command should come after the third `&&` to print the output of the last three variable declarations?**

The purpose of printing the output is to just neatly show the output of the three commands in one place, ordinal, perhaps in a table-like manner, comfortable to read (much more comfortable than say `set -x` traces).

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172244/how-can-i-print-only-variables-defined-inside-my-shell-script

Comment: @fpmurphy if I understand correctly this deals with running a script file, but I mean to a more general form of just working with the CLUI without running any particular file.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to do it.  Here I'm using a bash function, if you're using a different shell you might have to tweak it:

```bsh
printVariables() {
    local maxLen=0

    # Figure out the length of the longest variable name
    for i; do
        if ((${#i} > maxLen)); then
            maxLen=${#i}
        fi
    done

    # Make room for the colon
    maxLen=$((maxLen + 1))

    # Print the named variables
    for i; do
        printf "%-${maxLen}s %s\n" "${i}:" "${!i}"
    done
}
```

Then:

```
$ read domain &&
web_application_root="${HOME}/www" &&
domain_dir="${web_application_root}/${domain}/public_html" &&
printVariables domain web_application_root domain_dir
example.com
```

Will produce the following output:

```
domain:               example.com
web_application_root: /home/user/www
domain_dir:           /home/user/www/example.com/public_html
```